# Bash loop string and add string to it

Tags: string, bash, shell, loops

Hello I want my script to output the following:

```
string1 string2
string1 string2 string2
string1 string2 string2 string2
string1 string2 string2 string2 string2
```

Etc. for about 20 times or so.

I've tried the following:

```
#! /bin/bash
string1=hello
string2=world

#for {i=1;i=<10;i=i+1};
#echo $string1 + $string2
#!/bin/bash
for ((number=1;number < 10;number++))
do
echo $string1 $string3
string2 *10
done;
exit 0
```

Now I can't find anything on the web about just looping and adding strings..
Thanks for any help!
Greets

Comment: `s1="hello";s2="world"; for i in {1..10}; do s1="$s1 $s2"; echo $s1; done`

Comment: @gtato Please don't use brace expansions for iteration. Either use the C-style `for` loop as seen in the question, or use a `while` loop for POSIX compatibility.

Comment: @chepner: Oops... First time I heard about that POSIX compatibility.

Comment: hi @chepner, what about `for i in $(seq 10)` ?

Comment: That's worse; now you have an external process generating the full list of values up front instead of having the shell doing it internally. (I should say, `{...}` is OK for generating non-sequential ranges like `{foo,bar,baz}.{txt,png,gif}`. Just don't use it for "predictable" sequences you can generate from a formula in constant space.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bash syntax is not correct.

```
#!/bin/bash

string1=hello
string2=world
output=$string1" "$string2

for i in {1..10} ; do
  echo $output
  output=$output" "$string2
done
```

**Edit:** or, taking into account the comments below for the sake of beauty of code:

```
#!/bin/bash

string1="hello"
string2="world"
output="$string1 $string2"

for ((i = 1; i <= 10; i++)) ; do
  echo "$output"
  output+=" $string2"
done
```

Comment: Hi, you also can do this:
output+=" $string2"

Comment: `output="$string1 $string"` would be the more idiomatic quoting style.

Comment: The other quoting errors should also be fixed.  http://shellcheck.net/ can provide more detailed diagnostics.

Comment: With `string1+=" $string2"` before the `echo` you can skip both lines with `output`. Disadvantage of this, is that the value of `string1` is changed.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by writing to a variable, appending to it in an inner loop and then `echo` it out:

```
string1="string1"
string2="string2"
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do
  output="$string1"
  for ((j=1;j<=$i;j++)); do
    output+=" $string2"
  done
  output+=
  echo $output
done
```

Comment: `bash` also supports a more concise `+=` operator: `output+=" $string2"`. (Prefer lowercase variables to all-uppercase, which are reserved for the shell.)